# HAMC-SHA1 signature creation using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to HMAC-SHA1 signature creation using javascript. I found this code, in that i don't know, parameter 'secret' value.

```
 <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha256.js">   </script>
    <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>

   <script>
     var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("Message", "secret");
     var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
     document.write(hashInBase64);
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `secret` is just the key you use to create the signed hash, it's up to you to decide it.

Keep in mind that, since it is client side code, anyone looking the page source can see it!

Answer (score 0):

we can use Crypto for creating the HmacSHA1 signature using our consumer secret code and body data with the current date see the code below.

```
**#import the crypto js in your machine.....**

 import cryptoJs from "crypto-js";
```

**#secret (consumer secret key) #message (body data with current date)**

```
  const signature = cryptoJs.HmacSHA1(JSON.stringify(message), 
   secret).toString();
```

[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am8PW.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).